# How to clear the value of javascript global variable on click router in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have one javascript function :

```
function Letter(){
   if(typeof Letter.instance === 'object'){
       return Letter.instance;
   }
   Letter.instance = this;
   var self = this;

   this.getList = function(id, key, startdate, enddate){
       console.log(Letter.qList);

       var url = getURL() +'?id=' + id + '&key='+ key + '&start=' + +'&end=' + enddate;
       Letter.qList = ajaxRequest(url,"GET","json","application/json",0);

       console.log(Letter.qList);
   };
}
Letter.qList = null;
```

`qList` is a global variable of `Letter`.

This is backbone view:

```
var letterHistory = new Letter();
var CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

    },
    events : {
        'click #search' : 'searchLetterHistory'
    },
    'searchLetterHistory' : function(){
        letterHistory.getList('106','891177-0002','2012-08-07T13:58:19.403','2013-08-17T14:47:35.15');
    },
    render: function(){
        letterHistory.getList('106','','2012-08-07T13:58:19.403','2013-08-17T14:47:35.15'); 
        this.$el.append("<button id='search'>Search history</button>");
    }
});
return CustomerView;
```

This is the result in `render()` of the view when I route to `#customer`

[image]

After click on a button :

[image]

Problem : when I go the `#home` router, and come back to `#customer`, I suppose the result would show as the first picture (`qList` is set to null) but it didn't like what I thought, `qList` is still keeping the value in it.

So how could I clear the global variable(qList) whenever I route to the other router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set  Letter.qList = null; qList is a "static" variable to Letter

```
  if(typeof Letter.instance === 'object'){
   Letter.qList = null;
   return Letter.instance;
}
```

or you can call Letter.qList = null; every where from your code

Comment: So what should I do with it, to delete it as in my question.

Comment: if(typeof Letter.instance === 'object'){ delete Letter.qList; 
      return Letter.instance;
  }

Comment: sory it must be Letter.qList = null; pls see my updated answer

Comment: I'd tried your updated answer Azzy Elvul, but it is not work. When I go to #home then back to #customer, the object still has the value. it is going to null, if I do refreshing to the page. But I don't want to refresh it(this issue occur since I'm not yet update my code with your answer).

Comment: How you going to #home? it must be call new Letter() to clear the qList or somewhere you must call Letter.qList = null; Because Letter.qList is a "static" it will hold it;s value until the Letter is "alive" object.

Comment: Are there any way beside instantiate the new object to clear that static variable?

Comment: Would you like to see, how I instant `CustomerView` in the router?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44859/discussion-between-azzy-elvul-and-domo)

Comment: After I instantiated the object in router, and set the global variable to null, it works now. Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `qList` attribute when returning the existing object:

```
function Letter(){
  if(typeof Letter.instance === 'object'){
      delete Letter.qList; // *** notice this line ***
      return Letter.instance;
  }
  Letter.instance = this;
  var self = this;

  this.getList = function(id, key, startdate, enddate){
      console.log(Letter.qList);

      var url = getURL() +'?id=' + id + '&key='+ key + '&start=' + +'&end=' + enddate;
      Letter.qList = ajaxRequest(url,"GET","json","application/json",0);

      console.log(Letter.qList);
  };
```

}

Comment: The same issue occur.

Comment: I believe this is not will work. Domo try to make Letter to act as singleton so delete Letter.qList must be inside  in first if